# "\r" in html made by cakePHP Sanitize::clean()

Tags: php, html, cakephp, special-characters

I used Sanitize::clean in cakePHP to sanitize user input and in result I got "\r" character.

1. What does this character mean ("\r") ?
2. Is there a function that does the reverse of Sanitize::clean, so I can use before outputting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of this character (and others) by calling `trim($userInput);` or this way using `Sanitize::clean` :

```
$opts = array('carriage'=>true);
$cleaned = Sanitize::clean($userInput,$opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

"\r" is the Carriage Return character (when printing to the console, it causes output to start on the next line but does not affect display of web pages).

Comment: I believe that it is the Windows return character, and while necessary for some operations (writing to a notepad doc I think requires it), "\n" will also work in the console, and for many (most?) uses.